# How to translate (__('Invoice ') . $invoice->getIncrementId())?

Tags: invoice, magento2.2.2, email-translation

How to translate below string in pdf invoice  attachment from fooman extension

```
(__('Invoice ') . $invoice->getIncrementId())
```

I am not able to translate the attachment name. It is in php file. Can anybody please help to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

To add translation CSV file in Magento2, you just need to add a folder named "i18n" inside your module's folder, i.e.

```
app/code/Namespace/Module/i18n
```

In your case, you can put it in fooman module.

Then create a CSV file with name of language code.

For example:

- for english (United state) => en_US.csv
- french (canada) => fr_CA.csv

Inside CSV file you just need to add words which you want to translate, in following manner:

```
"<word in english language>","<word in language to convert>"
```

In your case, you can use below

```
"Invoice ","Your translation here"
```

Comment: other translations are working fine.only this invoice attachment is not working